# How to use Stripe Element Into Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I have a Laravel project. I want to add Stripe payment system in my Laravel app. In stripe there is js Element but unfortunately I cannot use it in blade files. Can anyody help me suggest other way to do this?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stripe Payment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Mount the instance within a <label> -->
    <label>Card
        <div id="card-element"></div>
    </label>
  
    <!--
    Or create a <label> with a 'for' attribute,
    referencing the ID of your container.
    -->
    <label for="card-element">Card</label>
    <div id="card-element"></div>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script>
        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_....');
        
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const cardElement = elements.create("payment", {"clientSecret": "sk_test_...."});
 
        cardElement.mount('#card-element');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _In stripe there is js Element but unfortunately I cannot use it in blade files._ Nonsense. Of course you can. You can use _any_ JavaScript in Blade files.

Comment: I know javascript can be used. I mean to say that this is not working. card element is working but payment element is not.

Comment: Right. So what error do you get? Or do we have to guess as to what you mean by “not working”?

Comment: One thing I note immediately is your "clientSecret" is wrong. You seem to be passing a Stripe secret API key, which is not correct. The way it's meant to work is you create a PaymentIntent through an API call on your backend server and return that to the frontend. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements